# How do I know whether to use standard Java networking or Java RMI?

Tags: java, network-programming, rmi

I'm debating whether I should use java RMI or standard Java networking for an application i'm working on.

The app will be a networked system that has heartbeat sensors and failsafe-features. So it's a 3-tiered system, with at least a DB and java application.

So if my Database fails on one machine, I'd like the 2nd machine to "sense" this.

I'm a bit confused about Java RMI, whether it's worth it to learn it.

Or if I use standard Java networking , I can do the same as RMI? I mean, if I really know the Java networking  well.

Thanks!

Comment: If you use RMI, you say goodbye to interoperability with other languages... Do you really want to go that route?

Comment: normally, RMI works over TCP. If you are comfortable w/ TCP or any other framework feel free to use it. RMI is basically serialization+proxies + object register + TCP.

Comment: @fge, interoperability is vastly overrated but yet you can use RMI interfaces, just need to implement the marshling yourself if you need interoperability but then you'd not ask on SO to boot

Comment: @bestsss you say "vastly overrated", I say "vastly underrated". I see no reason to use RMI when you can convey just as much information, if not more, using more standard means such as, for instance, JSON.

Comment: If you want to transmit Java Objects from one machine to another, it's much simpler to look towards and RMI solution.  If not, then a `Socket` solution is probably going to be less painful in the long run (once you get your protocol up and running)

Comment: @fge - well , in my case this is an academic project  - and at the moment I'm wanting something that works. Later I'd certainly want interoperability .

Comment: @Adel many things can work. I was talking about JSON: you just need a JSON parsing library on all ends and bare sockets will do what you want. What is more, it is just plain text, therefore very easy to debug.

Comment: @fge - hmm JSON - actually you're right . I will study this ,.  thanks

Comment: @bestsss What do you mean 'normally'? What RMI implementation is there that doesn't work over TCP?

Comment: @EJP, you can define your own SocketFactory.  There is one over http (which is tcp of course as well). However, i had one that uses jgroups and it can run over UDP or even memory mapped files.

Comment: @fge, mentioning json for anything serious is not serious, it's even slower than normal synchronization (which is not super fast on its own), json has no validation which alone is a huge turn off if you are willing to sacrifice speed. I would assume server based communication (i.e. cluster).  If you wish to use RMI over inet w/ custom clients, you are already thinking it wrong anyways.

Comment: @bestsss JSON _has_ validation, that is called JSON Schema. As to being slow, well, have long haven't you been doing JSON?

Comment: @fge, i thought json-schema is still in draft and has no official release yet. You can code any validation as you wish, but there is no standard one. JSON will always be slow: even converting double->string is not fast, yet the standard way to traverse the object graph will be good-old reflection (serialization uses sun.misc.Unsafe) and calling the getters and "stringifying" the data. JSON is a text-based protocol, you can't even compare it to a good binary one, it'd be orders of magnitude slower.

Comment: @bestsss JSON Schema is used over the internet -- and it is now at draft v4 BTW. And saying that JSON is slow means you _really_ have not tried Jackson, for instance.

Comment: @fge, yes it is in draft like I've told. and just reviewed the code of jackson it does exactly what I tell above: it can't be fast. Converting double->string is slow, even this one is non-trivial but base64 is truly mockery for binary data. If you have no good control to compare I can't help here. Try your hand at manually wring a protocol, preferably via DirectBuffers and compare it to json.Saying that, there are tons of string based protocol used even in trading software (even json is), FIX is a prime example for crappy protocol w/ huge adoption, still the adoption doesn't makes it 'fast'.

Comment: @bestsss I won't. JSON is plenty fast enough, and interoperable -- no need to go further as far as I'm concerned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days it is pretty easy to set up web services using SOAP or REST. With REST you can use XML or JSON messages without really having to know all about it. All these types of services can be accessed from .NET code or PHP or Javascript. (Well ... SOAP is sort of a pain except in .NET and Java. //personal opinion )

Spring can help you set up a service and a client interface to it is pretty easy. Fairly close to standard Annotations on bean classes and business methods define the interfaces and Spring does the heavy lifting. (I'm talking about Spring Web Services and not the Spring Remoting, though that would work as well. Spring Remoting isn't much better than RMI IMHO.)

You can also use Jersey (JAX-WS) or Jackson (Parse JSON) to do the remoting. Standard Annotations on bean classes and what-not build the interfaces. CXF will do JAX-WS and JAX-RS as well. Those are Java standards for building services and clients that communicate via remote messages.

Alternatively there are eclipse tools for generating both sides of the remote interface. All are tied to some framework (Axis-2 or CXS are some). Its sort of a code generation thing.

You might want to look into these a bit and see which one resonates with the way you look at things.

I know that I prefer all of these over using RMI. But I haven't used RMI directly in a long time.

Answer (score 1):

RMI is higher level protocol compared to the bare TCP/IP support in Java via Socket class that you seem to refer to as "Java networking". If the only thing your system does is sending heartbeats and there are just few nodes you should choose RMI for simplicity reasons. As all of the participants are JVMs there is no need for any interop and extra libraries to support that and as the number of participants is limited there is no need to consider anything fancy.